# Flutter google places autocomplete on text form field

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, textfield, google-places-autocomplete

I want a text form field with flutter google places autocomplete, that when the user select the location, the text will go to the text form field.

I have this code where the user clicks on the text form field, on tap, open the search address bar, but the text does not show on the text form field after selecting the address.

**Code**

```
TextFormField(
                          decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            hintText: "Enter Company Address",
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.map),
                          ),
                          onTap: () async {
                            Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                              context: context,
                              radius: 10000000,
                              types: [],
                              strictbounds: false,
                              apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                              mode: Mode.overlay,
                              language: "en",
                              components: [Component(Component.country, "nz")],
                            );
                          },
                          validator: (val) =>
                              val.isEmpty ? 'Enter address' : null,
                          onChanged: (val) async {
                            setState(() => address = val);
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: It doesn't work magically. Read into `TextEditingController _stackOverflow`, create one, assign it to your textfield, and when you get results back from api, `_stackOverflow.text= responseFromApi`

Comment: Yeah, I managed to make it work with controller, thanks

Comment: Great, you're most welcome! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to create a
`TextEditingController _place = TextEditingController()`

Then, when the result comes back from the API, for example, `components[0]`,
You assign this `String` value to the `controller.

`_place.text = result`. It'll change the UI without using setState even.